# Is this normal?

Tags: 14.04, system

So, I installed Ubuntu, when it finishes installing it spits out the disk and there is a purple and white mosaic on my screen, is this normal? Using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop-amd64+mac.iso
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be a problem with the video driver: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233163  . What graphics card does your computer have?

Comment: We can't see the image, please upload to http://imgur.com and give us the link.

Comment: I apologize for that, it was late and since I am new here I have not "earned enough points" to upload a photo yet

Comment: here is that link: http://imgur.com/GTf3X7Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue with your graphics card; I saw such artifacts on an old Lenovo T420.  By default, Ubuntu will install the free nouveau graphics driver; and that driver caused all kinds of "interesting" effects on that laptop. In the end, I installed the nvidia driver - resolving all the strange problems that I encountered before.

Comment: Thanks, I shall give it a try, Ubuntu is uncharted territory for me, now that I am taking the plunge, I was like *uh oh, what just happened* I think I saw on the homepage's release notes stating that it was a bug issue, and to just do a hard reset in the meantime.